# Show Process list Magento, queries are set to "sleep"

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, deadlock

I am running one magento 1.9.2.4 instance, When I open my website and check process list using

```
Show Processlist
```

in mysql it shows multiple of queries set to "sleep". I am only opening one static page, which contains header,footer and static content of a cms page.

See Screenshot.
[image]

When I check with

```
Show full processlist;
```

It does not show any queries. There is no query logged in mysql and it is slow to open the query log also.

Please let me know what does this mean?
Why it is only in a Magento Project, it is not happening in Core PHP project?

Tell me if any information from my side is required.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I faced it hours ago and could solve it by deleting malicious sql injections in catalogsearch_query database table.

Comment: Yes, I turned off first visitor log data. Follow my below code in app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KevinKrieger Yes, I turned on Memcache on server also switch off logs in magento. Follow my below code in app/etc/local.xml

To Enable Memcache for Magento after enabling it on server.

```
<cache>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
    <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
        <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
        <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
        <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
        <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
        <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
    </memcached>
</cache>
```

To Turn off all logs 

    
        
            disabled
        
        
            disabled
        
        
            disabled
        
        
            disabled
        
        
            disabled
        
        
            disabled

```
    <catalog_controller_product_view>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </catalog_controller_product_view>
    <catalog_product_compare_add_product>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </catalog_product_compare_add_product>
    <catalog_product_compare_item_collection_clear>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </catalog_product_compare_item_collection_clear>
    <catalog_product_compare_remove_product>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </catalog_product_compare_remove_product>
    <customer_logout>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </customer_logout>
    <sales_quote_item_save_before>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </sales_quote_item_save_before>
    <sendfriend_product>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </sendfriend_product>
    <wishlist_add_product>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </wishlist_add_product>
    <wishlist_share>
        <observers><reports><type>disabled</type></reports></observers>
    </wishlist_share>
</events>
```